# Makefile: Unable to assign output of a command to a variable

Tags: bash, makefile

Below is a section from the `Makefile` where I wanted to assign the output of `poetry show -v | awk 'FNR <= 1' | awk 'FNR <= 1' | cut -d':' -f 2 | xargs;` to the variable PP, but the value is never assigned, as in the output below

**Makefile**

```
install:
    poetry install; \
    poetry show -v | awk 'FNR <= 1' | cut -d':' -f 2 | xargs; \
    PP=$(poetry show -v | awk 'FNR <= 1' | cut -d':' -f 2 | xargs); \
    echo $$PP; \
    source $$PP/bin/activate
```

**Output**

```
(venv) ➜  xxxxxxx git:(main) ✗ make install
poetry install; \
        poetry show -v | awk 'FNR <= 1' | cut -d':' -f 2 | xargs; \
        PP=; \
        echo $PP; \
        source $PP/bin/activate
Installing dependencies from lock file

No dependencies to install or update
/Users/xxxxx/ssa/code/xxxxxxx/.venv

/bin/sh: /bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

Any help appreciated.. Thanks.

Comment: `awk 'FNR <= 1' | awk 'FNR <= 1'` looks like a really unobvious way to write `head -n 1` ... or more precisely `head -n 1 | head -n 1`

Comment: Forgive me, I'm not a shell script expert, not even close :)

Comment: `$(poetry show -v ...` will be evaluated by `make` when it reads the `makefile`.  To defer execution to the shell try `$$(poetry show -v ...` instead.